# How to parse Html formatted element

Tags: javascript, string

```
var div = document.getElementById('test');
var str = '<p>Just some <span>text</span> here</p>';
var temp = document.createElement('div');

temp.innerHTML = str;
while (temp.firstChild) {
    div.appendChild(temp.firstChild);
}
```

string is defined in one line I required in formatted style like below

```
var str = '<p>
             Just some
             <span>text</span>
              here
           </p>';
```

how to pass this string or html content to javscript.. it will be easy to modify..I too lone content to add so asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For multiline strings, add `\` at the end of line.

```
var str = '<p>\
             Just some\
             <span>text</span>\
              here\
           </p>';
```

[*Blog*](http://davidwalsh.name/multiline-javascript-strings)

Comment: @Digigizmo Yes, I think. Did you notice `var str = '<p>Just some <span>text</span> here</p>';
var temp = document.createElement('div');` in the code